# How to manage SSL with external libraries

Tags: symfony, ssl, https

In my Symfony2 application, I have set up an SSL certificate.

My browser says there is some insecure content on my page. When I take a look at the console logs, I see that jQuery and other libraries are not loaded over HTTPS.

Can I solve this without hardcoding HTTPS?

What is the best way to make all this work?

Comment: How do you load jquery and the other libraries?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Specify the URLs to the insecure assets with leading `//`, i.e.: instead of ...

```
<script src="http://example.com/jquery.js"></script>
```

... use:

```
<script src="//example.com/jquery.js"></script>
```

Comment: nice ! I did not think of this!

Comment: and how would you do for links generated with asset twig function ?